# Receiving error objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue

Tags: iphone, xcode, exc-bad-access

I was fixing some leaks I had in my code today and in doing so I have received this error when running my code on my device(simulator works fine). I have attached a picture to show my error.

I assume my code has nothing to do with it since on the simulator it works fine. I have tried to look it up but have found nothing that has worked for me. I know this has something to do with ARC, which I am using.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image]

Comment: Could you post the contents of `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have posted an assembly code dump of the `obj_retain` function. The breakpoint handler indicates it is trying to load a value from an invalid memory address.

Based on the helpfully named `objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue`, it would appear that a function/method, that claims to return an Objective-C object, is actually returning a junk value (invalid pointer) and the runtime is crashing when it tries to retain it.

It's very weird that the main thread stack is only two levels deep.

Do you have optimizations turned on? Usually they are off in Debug mode and on in Release mode. I've run into bugs before where I forgot to initialize a pointer variable; in Debug mode it was defaulting to 0, so code worked fine, but in Release mode it would get a garbage value and cause a crash.

That's about all I can say, there's not much useful information in your screenshot.

Comment: I turn my Debug optimization levels as 'Fastest,Smallest' and I can know switch between tabs but I can go into one tab. Ill investigate further. Thanks for your help @benzado

Comment: @benzado I have the exact same error with the same two level stack. It happened during Debug mode and I have optimizations off. Any idea how I can find out which object is the culprit (if I can find out the memory address, I can possibly 'po' on it in the debugger)?

Comment: @fishinear Not sure. Try posting a new question with as much detail as you can.

Comment: @benzado Never mind, I found the problem. I was using a layer's drawInContext: method from a background thread (for an off-screen context), while its delegate was already dealloc'ed on the main thread. I'll add an answer to hint in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the debugger at what the other threads are doing at the moment of the crash. You may be using objects on a background thread that are or have been dealloc'ed on the main thread already. If another thread is in the middle of doing something when the crash occurs, then that is a likely cause.

The exact same error occurred for me, and that was the cause in my case.

It is still not clear to me why the error appeared on the main thread, not on the background thread, and why it only showed two entries on the main thread stack. Possibly ARC is doing some memory cleanup work between main thread runloop invocations. I can imagine it does not like the dealloc'ed memory being overwritten by another thread.